# How to make user control like application bar - windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, application-bar

My question seems to be a bit strange. I have a long list selector and I want to add a control like application bar in it so it can be repeated many times the same with the controls in the item template. I thought about a grid with the contents I want, but how can I make this Grid slides up and down ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is strange but you can certainly try it. There is no definite way to do this but you can create a user control that would be the application bar like element you want and add it to the list selector. But the biggest problem is make it slide up and down. In the user control you can do this easily but there are many ways you can do this. You have to try it out and see. Use animations and story boards to animate the sliding effect. This can be done using Blend for Visual Studio. But you might run in to a problem where even though you did the animation of your application bar sliding in your Application bar like user control, it might not work in the list selector because the layout and the size of a single list item needs to change as the user expands the user control to have the sliding effect. As i said, there are many ways one can do this. You have to try it out and build it.

Answer (score -1):

List item

In App.xaml type in this code

```
<Application.Resources>
  <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="UserControlAppBar" ForegroundColor="White" BackgroundColor="Black" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="button1" IconUri="/Assets/Images/appbar/img1.png" Text="News" Click="button1_Click"/>
    <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
      <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="MenuItem" Text="Menu1" Click="Menu1_Click"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
  </shell:ApplicationBar>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: In App.xaml type in this code

<Application.Resources>

<shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="UserControlAppBar" ForegroundColor="White" BackgroundColor="Black" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="button1" IconUri="/Assets/Images/appbar/img1.png" Text="News" Click="button1_Click"/>
            
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="MenuItem"  Text="Menu1" Click="Menu1_Click"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
</Application.Resources>

Comment: Once you have done this in your App.xaml you can use the app bar in your app by writing this code just below <phone:PhoneApplicationPage (right on the second line of your XAML page)

ApplicationBar="{StaticResource UserControlAppBar}"

Comment: There is something wrong. the code winthin the tags  ( < and > ) is not getting displayed. I don't know that the issue is exacltly.

Comment: Probably what you need to do is to indent it all by 4 spaces so it's marked as a code block and the browser doesn't try to process it as html.  You can do that by selecting the code and clicking the {} icon.  IF that doesn't work, edit the code in and leave a comment below.  It's a lot easier for someone else to edit your answer to fix the formatting if we don't have to figure linebreaks as well (which would be the case copying from the comments).